# Angular Universal Firebase Deploy - Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dist/project-name/server/main'

Tags: angular, firebase, angular-universal

I am trying to deploy my Angular Universal application through firebase function, but I am seeing this weird error message that I cannot find any similar error anywhere online.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.6.11",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "prebuild": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng lint --fix",
    "build": "ng deploy",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run project-name:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/project-name/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build --prod && ng run project-name:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run project-name:prerender"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/fire": "^6.0.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/material": "^11.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~11.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngrx/store": "^10.1.2",
    "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^11.0.1",
    "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^8.2.6",
    "angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "domino": "^2.1.6",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "firebase": "^8.2.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "globalthis": "^1.0.1",
    "ng-snotify": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-image-compress": "^11.0.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "preboot": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sitemap-generator": "^8.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": ">= 0.900 < 0.1100",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1100.5",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "0.8.0-beta.6",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "0.8.0-beta.6",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "0.8.0-beta.6",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^0.8.0-beta.7",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "0.8.0-beta.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.0.5",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "10.1.0",
    "@nguniversal/builders": "^11.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.19.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.2",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'globalthis/auto';

import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';

const domino = require('domino');

import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/project-name/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  const window = domino.createWindow(indexHtml);
  (global as any)['document'] = window.document;

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

// Webpack will replace 'require' with '__webpack_require__'
// '__non_webpack_require__' is a proxy to Node 'require'
// The below code is to ensure that the server is run only when not requiring the bundle.
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';
```

firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "dist/project-name",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Content-Language",
              "value": "ko"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
              "value": "*"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|webp|js|css|eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|woff2|font.css)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=31536000"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "404.html",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "max-age=300"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "project-name",
      "public": "dist/project-name/dist/project-name/browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "source": "dist/project-name"
  }
}
```

When I run 'ng deploy', I get the following messages:

```
=== Deploying to 'my-server'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing dist/project-name directory for uploading...
Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module './dist/project-name/server/main'
Require stack:
- /Users/uu/project/project-name/dist/project-name/index.js
- /Users/uu/project/project-name/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js

Try running "npm install" in your functions directory before deploying.
```

Does anyone have the same issue?

my node version is v14.15.4 and npm version is v6.14.10.

Also I don't think there is an issue with build since I can successfully run the project on my localhost when I compile using 'npm run dev:ssr'.

I would appreciate if someone could help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue. Did you solve? Thanks!